# HTML default href value

Tags: javascript, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have web page http://localhost...
I'have 2 different languages on web page: "en" and "ka". So my javascript application pushes state: http://localhost/ka (if there is not language parameter in url).

in HTML I have navigation href's:

```
<a href="/home">home</a>
<a href="/about">about</a>
```

this tags open: 
http://localhost/home
and
http://localhost/about

So my javascript application, pushes state again, because there is not language parameters.

I'm interested in, if it is possible somehow, to set default hostname or something, which helps me...

I want to my href url was http://localhost/ka/home and http://localhost/ka/about

Comment: You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rewrite your address, if you are on an Apache web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!ka/).*$ /ka/$0 [L,NC,R=302]
```

This will make `URI` as `/ka/<uri>` when only `/uri` is requested from clients.

Comment: Thank you, but what if instead of ka there is en?

Comment: Then rule would be `RewriteRule ^(?!en/).*$ /ka/$0 [L,NC,R=302]` Rule has no way to know whether you want to add `ka` or `en`.